# Thymeleaf Security (sec:authorize tag) doesn't work in Spring

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have a problem: when I implemented thymeleaf security, added dependency, I noticed that sec:authorize tag isn't even working!
I've browsed a lot of questions, but all of them obsolete or man forgot to add dependency
This tutorial is so easy, there weren't any additional classes and configurations, but it didn't help either: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-thymeleaf

My project on github: https://github.com/sedub01/CafeBarApplication, I haven't push new changes yet (if you'd noticed some files missed, I'll add them)
There is my pom.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>sia</groupId>
    <artifactId>CafeBarApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CafeBarApplication</name>
    <description>Cafe Bar Example</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Last, but not least: my html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">

<head>
    <title>Cafe Bar</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3 th:text="'Welcome' + (${fullname} ? ', ' + ${fullname} + '!' : '')" />
    <img th:src="@{/images/cafeIcon.png}" />
    <!-- TODO think about placing in header -->
    <form method="POST" th:action="@{/logout}">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
    <div sec:authorize="!isAuthenticated()">
        This content is only shown to unauthenticated users.
    </div>
    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
        This content is only shown to authenticated users.
    </div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        This content is only shown to administrators.
    </div>
    <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
        This content is only shown to users.
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Actual result (I've logined as USER, but every div is displayed):
[image]

Comment: The library `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` you have used is not supporting spring security 6. As spring-boot version 3.x.x supports spring version > 6.x.x. Use `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6` package instead.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar haha, it's absurd, but that worked! I don't know how I should have guessed this error
Thank you and people like you!

Comment: I have added as an answer. If you can accept it as an answer then it will help others to get to the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you using spring-boot version 3.1.0 which uses spring 6.0.9 version. But the library you have used `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5` is using spring version 5.x so it will not work as expected.

Use the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6` library instead.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```